# Highlight specific column rows in Microsoft Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, macros, row, highlight

I want to present a list of data in an Access query and highlight specific rows which contain certain text. I also wondering if there is any great way to sort up, lets say "Transports" with different orders in groups with spaces between every unique transport.

I believe that I have to make a query and build a form for that with a bunch of macros? Or is it there any easier ways to go? Maybe any great guides similar this to follow? I'm kinda new on Access :)

Thanks for all the help, Cheers!

Comment: The tables themselves have no formatting or display attributes.  They way that Access accomplishes this is through Forms.  Forms are meant to be very easy to get up and running and they are.  However as a long term solution they are a poor choice.

Answer (score 1):

In Access you first design a database model by creating tables representing your entities and setting relations between them.

Then you create forms and reports based either directly on your tables or on queries. Tables and queries will very rarely be presented to the user directly in an application. This is very different from Excel, where a worksheet is the "database", the business logic (calculations), the user interface and the report at the same time. In Access you separate the data holding from the user interface (data input and reporting). It is also a good design principle to place the business logic in modules and class modules instead of "behind" the forms. Access is an application development environment and not just a tool for entering data.

In forms you can set the `Allow Datasheet View` property to `Yes` and the `Default View` property to `Datasheet` in order to simulate a table. In the TextBoxes you can use conditional formatting (Menu *Format* > *Conditional Formatting...*). Here you can define up to three conditions and formattings that will be applied when the condition is fulfilled. Together with the base formatting of your TextBox this gives you four possible looks for each column.

Grouping in forms is not possible; however, in reports you can insert several nested grouping levels and insert group headers and footers.

Comment: grouping is possible with subforms

Comment: Thanks for a good explanation Oliver. Brad I will have a look at this. But lets say I have all my tables filled with data, created the relations and made a query for them. What is the best way to present "picking lists" for an employee with Transports that contains different orders in each transport and spacing between each unique transport. And with highlights on specific orders that contains certain text in the list. The goal is to make daily picking lists which are sorted by transports.

Comment: You have employees having transports, having orders. Therefore you would have a selection form for employees allowing the user to search and filter employees. Then you could open one of these employees in a new form showing employee data plus a list of transports. Here you can select and open a transport in yet another form. In this form you will display transport related data plus a list of orders. Finally in this list you can pick an order and open it in a form to see its related data in detail.

Comment: There is only one employee handling the whole list with transports. Today I get the list with all todays transports from access with an update button in an excel file. The problem is I want more spacing between them that seperates the different transports with space for the employee. Is there any way to do this automaticly? Cheers!

Comment: I do not understand. You have only one employee, but you want space between employees?